# Vuejs 2 make a global function and pass param

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In a component i am changing the title and description in mounted() but i want to make a global function so i can reuse the code below.

How can i achieve that?

```
window.document.title = 111;                            
document.head.querySelector('meta[name=description]').content = 222;

function getTitle(title){
    return window.document.title = title;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution for this:

```
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        makeTitle: function (title) {
            return window.document.title = title;
        }
    }
});


export default{
    props: ['slug'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            items: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.makeTitle(this.slug);
    },
```